Choosing decimal places in sensor measurements
I have an exercise in which I am asked to compare the temperature detected by a thermal imaging camera on some foods with those detected by a thermocouple inserted under the surface of the food. For this purpose, I am asked to find a thermal imaging camera and one or more thermocouples including conditioning and display that allow me to detect the temperature with a precision of 2 degrees centigrade and I am asked to pay attention to the use of decimals when writing the values ​​detected by the thermal imaging camera and the thermocouples in a table.
How do I choose the necessary decimals based on the value displayed on the thermal imaging camera and the required precision? And what about the thermocouples? The problem I am facing is how to choose the minimum number of decimals required to satisfy the required precision based on the number of digits on the display.

Not really an electronics problem, it's a measurement presentation problem, which doesn't really fit into mathematics or computer science neatly. Perhaps statistics. But it often comes down to the engineer to decide.
The resolution of your display should be tailored to match the noise of the measurement, and the precision you are aiming for.
Unfortunately, you don't give the expected noise of your sensors.
With a requested precision of 2 degrees however, 0.1 resolution would be plenty. One order of magnitude finer adds little further error. Any more decimal places would be meaningless, known as 'empty precision'. Any fewer would be a big contributor to the total error.
